# Chrome and Safari Hack

Tags: html, css, browser

I have the following style:

```
table.jqTransformTextarea td#jqTransformTextarea-mm textarea{
    margin:0;
}
```

This works as expected in Firefox, Opera, Internet Explorer 7,8 and 6.

However, to make it work in Chrome and Safari I need to do:

```
table.jqTransformTextarea td#jqTransformTextarea-mm textarea{
    margin:10px 0 0 10px;
}
```

How can I set this style to Chrome and Safari only?
I would prefer not to use JavaScript (or jQuery) to get this effect, and get the solution with CSS only, or HTML (but I don't know if there is a tag like: `<!--[if IE]>` that selects this two browsers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just solved my own question:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)
{ table.jqTransformTextarea td#jqTransformTextarea-mm textarea { margin:10px 0 0 10px; } }
```

Comment: I'm going to try this, but it doesn't look future-proof to me; eventually the min-device-pixel-ratio property will come out of beta and the -webkit prefix will be removed.